# self and scope in ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Graph < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :data_source

    pp self.method_defined? :fdsafdafewafd
    pp self.method_defined? :data_source
    self.data_source
end
```

The above code produces an interesting interaction that I'm not sure I understand.

```
self.method_defined? :fdsafdafewafd
```

predictably, this returns false

```
self.method_defined? :data_source
```

predictably, this returns true

```
self.data_source
```

This causes:

```
NoMethodError:   undefined method `data_source' for
#<Class:0x0055dd1d71c6e0>
```

My question is, given this fact (which I suspect has something to do with scope), why does the line above it return true?  If the method is not defined in this scope, shouldn't method_defined? return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_attached_file :data_source` adds an *instance method* to the `Graph` class called `data_source`. That's why `self.method_defined? :data_source` returns `true`.

However, when you do `self.data_source` (equivalent to `Graph.data_source`), you're invoking the method `:data_source` on the `Graph` class itself, which is not defined; hence the error.  You can only invoke that method on objects of the Graph class.

If you were to create a new instantiation of Graph, e.g. `g = Graph.new`, then you could do `g.data_source` as expected.